# How to redirect to login page is session experies

Tags: php, cakephp

Iam new to cakephp and iam using auth for my login utiities...I want to redirect to the login page incase of my session experies for all my actions ...I wrote code like\

```
public function index() {        
    if(!$this->Session->read('username'))
        $this->logout();
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());        
}
```

but for all my actions such as add(),edit()...every time I need to check for session variable...if I write the condition in __construct like

```
public function __construct()
{
    if(!$this->Session->read('username'))
        $this->logout();
}
```

it giving me error like

```
Error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object
```

can anyone suggest me

Comment: try [Auth Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (!$this->Session->valid()) {
  $this->logout();
}
```

Comment: Nope...it giving me "Error: Call to a member function valid() on a non-object 
"

Comment: What about session->check()?

Comment: Same Error: Call to a member function check() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have included the SessionComponent.

Try to add

`$components = array('Session');`

in your `AppController` first.

Then check the documentation for more information: http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-SessionComponent.html

Comment: Can you post your full controller code? and code from your AppController ?

Comment: Also try to rebuild these two examples from the Cookbook. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html.  If you have to check your session in _EVERY_ action in _EVERY_ controller you're doing something wrong. Cake already provides this functionality in the AuthComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Using `AuthComponent` if session expires and user tries to access a protected page he will be automatically redirected to login page.